# How would I have my bot’s status be how many discord servers it is in? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiAPa.jpg)

I want to have my bot automatically update it’s status to the amount of servers it’s currently in, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bot.guilds to get a guild count and then input that into your status on startup. Something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    servers = bot.guilds
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(f'on {servers} Servers'))
```